# MariaDB ODBC Connector is returning a Char Field for a COUNT(*)

Tags: mariadb, odbc, foxpro

I've been trying to migrate a Foxpro application from MySQL ODBC connector to MariaDB ODBC connector.

While I've been testing the new connector, I found that every COUNT(*) field in SQL queries is being created in the cursors as a Char fields (instead of a Numeric field).

I've been reviewing the connector settings, the server settings, comparing server settings between the development server and a MariaDB-XAMPP local server, to no avail. And, where I have a number being expected, since the SQL query returns a char, I get a "Data Type Mismatch" error.

Here is the minimal example that makes COUNT(*) return strings

```
LOCAL cConnectionString 
&&string is for default XAMPP MariaDB Server
cConnectionString ="Driver={MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver};SERVER=localhost;UID=root;DB=mydb;PORT=3306;OPTION=3" 
nOpt="3" 

* Establish the ODBC connection and return if fails
lnConnection = SQLStringConnect(cConnectionString)

cSQLQuery = "SELECT COUNT(id) as myCount from mytable"
lnResult = SQLEXEC(lnConnection, cSQLQuery, "mycursor") 

IF lnResult > 0
    select mycursor 
    typeOfCount=VARTYPE(mycursor.myCount)
    msg="MyCount vartype (expected N): "+typeOfCount+" ["+ALLTRIM(mycursor.myCount)+"] - Option: "+nOpt &&No STR() needed, its already a string
    MESSAGEBOX(msg)
ELSE
    MESSAGEBOX("Error executing SQL query:"+MESSAGE())
ENDIF
SQLDISCONNECT(lnConnection)

RETURN &&End the program
```

1.- I tried options from 1 to 332987 (throught a loop, no results, VARTYPE(myCount) was C all the time)
2.- I tried changing server configuration to be the same as one server which returned good results with MySQL ODBC (throught a function to set every global variable, no results).
3.- I Tried converting using COUNT(*)/1 syntax and this convertion works, but, per documentation, COUNT returns a bigint, not a char. Also, in application code, there are a lot of COUNTs. I found out Foxpro does not support bigints (like the ones in COUNT). I found in here:
[text](http://computer-programming-forum.com/2-vfp/e0f9ecced50dedf3.htm)
That I can do something like this:
DBSetProp("rv_view.bigintfield", "Field", "Datatype", "N(19)")
What would be the Prop to disable bigints in MariaDB ODBC?

4.-  In previous configuration, the MySQL ODBC Driver had an "OPTIONS=16387", and that includes converting bigints as ints. Is there a flag to do the same convertion in MariaDB ODBC Driver?

5.- I also traced both ODBC Drivers (MySQL ODBC / MariaDB ODBC), whats odd from there is, the SQLDescribeCol's SWORD value for column datatype parameter in MySQL ODBC is 4, and -5 in MariaDB ODBC. Maybe this is a bug in MariaDB ODBC Driver being unable to detect bigints?

Comment: It looks like MariaDB ODBC driver needs to support this option 16384 to report bigint fields as integer - that should solve your problem. I opened new feature ticket for that https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/ODBC-402

Comment: It was solved by installing MariaDB ODBC Connector 3.1.20. Thanks!